# React update array index before function execution

Tags: reactjs

I made a carousel. When I click on a thumbnail the image source changes. In the changeSrc function I log the state of selectedIndex. The first time I click on the thumbnail I get the old index, only the second time I click on a thumbnail I get the correct index in my console. Is there a way to update the index before the function is executed instead of after?

This also gives me problems when I add previous and next arrow buttons. Hopefully someone can help me?

**This is my code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Image from './components/Image'
import image1 from './assets/image1.jpg'
import image2 from './assets/image2.jpg'
import image3 from './assets/image3.jpg' 
import image4 from './assets/image4.jpg'

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageSrc : image1,
      images : [image1,image2,image3,image4],
      imageCaption : "landscape 1",
      selectedIndex : 0
    }
  }

  changeSrc = (caption, index) => {
    this.setState({imageCaption : caption});
    this.setState({selectedIndex : index});
    this.setState({imageSrc : this.state.images[index]});
    console.log(this.state.selectedIndex)
  }

  render(){

    return(
      <div className="container">
        <Image imageSrc={this.state.imageSrc} imageCaption={this.state.imageCaption}/>
        <div className="thumbs">
          <img onClick={() => this.changeSrc("landscape 1" , 0)} src={this.state.images[0]} alt="thumbnail 1"/>
          <img onClick={() => this.changeSrc("landscape 2", 1)} src={this.state.images[1]}alt="thumbnail 2"/>
          <img onClick={() => this.changeSrc("landscape 3", 2)} src={this.state.images[2]}alt="thumbnail 3"/>
          <img onClick={() => this.changeSrc("landscape 4", 3)} src={this.state.images[3]}alt="thumbnail 4"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Image extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="imageContainer">
        <img src={this.props.imageSrc} alt="landscape 1"/>
        <span className="caption">{this.props.imageCaption}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State update are not immediate and they are async and batched by React.

You are looking for callback after state update. Second argument in `setState` is a callback reference which gets executed once state gets updated which you can rely on.

Also since you are relying on value from your state within `setState` I changed it to functional `setState` which again guarantees you have latest state value at the time of update for `imageSrc`.

```
changeSrc = (caption, index) => {
  this.setState((previousState) => {
    imageCaption: caption,
    selectedIndex: index,
    imageSrc: previousState.images[index]
  }, () => console.log(this.state.selectedIndex))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reaction it works fine. I also try to add en nextImg function onClick. Here I have to click 2 times to see the next image. Can I use the same solution for this?

`nextImg = () =>{
    if(this.state.selectedIndex >= 0 && this.state.selectedIndex < this.state.images.length){
      this.setState(prevState => ({ selectedIndex: prevState.selectedIndex + 1}));
      this.setState({imageSrc : this.state.images[this.state.selectedIndex]});
    }
  }`

Comment: @JoeriGroot I'm not sure what you mean here, can you create an example possibly on codesandbox.io where I can take a look at on what you are trying to do, and since that's a followup question, create another question and let me know and I'll take a look or someone else may assist you sooner that way.

Comment: I have created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403605/react-carousel-update-index-before-function-execution). There you can also find a link to code sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you log the index in the function. Keep in mind that `setState` is asynchronous. So when you log the state like this:

```
this.setState({imageSrc : this.state.images[index]});
console.log(this.state.selectedIndex)
```

The index will always be the old index.