# React carousel update index before function execution

Tags: reactjs

I made a carousel. When I click on an arrow to show the next or previous image I have to click twice. The first time I click on the arrow the function uses the old index. I think the function is executed before the index is updated. Is there a way to solve this problem?

I have a code example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-snyder-8l582?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

**This is my code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Image from './components/Image'
import Arrows from './components/Arrows'
import image1 from './assets/image1.jpg'
import image2 from './assets/image2.jpg'
import image3 from './assets/image3.jpg' 
import image4 from './assets/image4.jpg'

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageSrc : image1,
      images : [image1,image2,image3,image4],
      imageCaption : "Groen landschap met boogje",
      selectedIndex : 0
    }
  }

  changeSrc = (caption, index) => {
    this.setState({imageCaption : caption});
    this.setState({selectedIndex : index});
    this.setState({imageSrc : this.state.images[index]});
    console.log(this.state.imageCaption)
    console.log(this.state.selectedIndex);
  }

  nextImg = () =>{
    if(this.state.selectedIndex >= 0 && this.state.selectedIndex < this.state.images.length){
      this.setState(prevState => ({ selectedIndex: prevState.selectedIndex + 1}));
      this.setState({imageSrc : this.state.images[this.state.selectedIndex]});
    }
  }

  prevImg = () =>{
    if(this.state.selectedIndex > 0 && this.state.selectedIndex <= this.state.images.length){
      this.setState(prevState => ({ selectedIndex: prevState.selectedIndex - 1}));
      this.setState({imageSrc : this.state.images[this.state.selectedIndex]});
      console.log(this.state.selectedIndex);
      console.log("kaas");
    }
  }

  render(){

    return(
      <div className="container">
        <Image imageSrc={this.state.imageSrc} imageCaption={this.state.imageCaption}/>
        <div className="thumbs">
          <img onClick={() => this.changeSrc("Groen landschap met boogje" , 0)} src={this.state.images[0]} alt="1 thumbnail"/>
          <img onClick={() => this.changeSrc("Geinig bruggetje door het water", 1)} src={this.state.images[1]}alt="2 thumbnail"/>
          <img onClick={() => this.changeSrc("Man genietend op een steiger", 2)} src={this.state.images[2]}alt="3 thumbnail"/>
          <img onClick={() => this.changeSrc("Echt vet mooie waterval", 3)} src={this.state.images[3]}alt="4 thumbnail"/>
        </div>
        <Arrows prevImg={this.prevImg} nextImg={this.nextImg}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Image extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="imageContainer">
        <img src={this.props.imageSrc} alt="landscape 1"/>
        <span className="caption">{this.props.imageCaption}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Image
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import arrowLeft from '../assets/arrowLeft.svg'
import arrowRight from '../assets/arrowRight.svg'

export default class Arrows extends Component {

  render() {
    const   prevImg =   this.props.prevImg;
    const   nextImg =   this.props.nextImg;
    return (
      <div>
        <img onClick={() => prevImg()} className="arrow arrowLeft" src={arrowLeft} alt="arrow left" />
        <img onClick={() => nextImg()} className="arrow arrowRight" src={arrowRight} alt="arrow right" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Not related to the root question but `const prevImg = this.props.prevImg;` then doing `onClick={() => prevImg()}` very unnecessary. Skip the const and inline and just do `onClick={this.props.prevImg}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to use the new value in state before its actually set. `setState` is async, so you cannot use its value immediately after updating it -- unless you use the optional callback.

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({ selectedIndex: prevState.selectedIndex + 1}));
// console.log(this.state.selectedIndex)
// this.state.selectedIndex is still 0!
this.setState({imageSrc : this.state.images[this.state.selectedIndex]});
```

This is leading to the lag in updates you're seeing. The state does get updated correctly, just not immediately. So here's the order of what's happening:

- onClick
- call to `setState` to update index to 1
- call to `setState` to update src to 0
- state updates are batched and actually completed
- re-render
- onClick
- call to `setState` to update index to 2
- call to `setState` to update src to 1

Change to this:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  selectedIndex: prevState.selectedIndex + 1
}),
() => {
  // The callback is executed AFTER the state is updated
  this.setState({
    imageSrc: this.state.images[this.state.selectedIndex]
  });
});
```

Or you could simplify things and only call `setState` once:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({ 
  selectedIndex: prevState.selectedIndex + 1,
  imageSrc: prevState.images[prevState.selectedIndex + 1]
}));
```